# Using an external url for a templateURL

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to use an external url for the templateUrl in the routing code of app.js file.

By external url, I mean a page such as "http://www.google.com".

This page will not work as a partial though, but I think removing the html and body tag with jQuery in the view controller would be an easy fix.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

For example, would I simply put "templateUrl: http://www.google.com, controller: "googleController".  In the router?

If so, I'm not quite sure what to do in the actual controller.

The answer is probably pretty obvious to most readers, but I'm pretty new to AngularJS and jQuery.

Comment: You could use an iframe in your partial.

Comment: You cannot do this as it violates the cross domain origin policy.

Comment: I am speaking on behalf of two domains that I own.